# How can I redownload apps I deleted outside of iTunes?

Tags: itunes, applications, data-synchronization, windows

When I stopped syncing my iPad to my PC I deleted the folder that had all my apps. Now I'm syncing again on a different hard drive, and I get the message

> The app "X" could not be used because the original file could not be found. Would you like to locate it?

Of course I can't locate it, and there's no Download option that I see if I right click. These apps are missing their icons in iTunes as well, and I don't really know how this will affect syncing.

Is there some way I can redownload these apps back onto my machine? It's iTunes for Windows if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If iTunes in the Cloud is available in your country (it is in most), go to the iTunes Store,  click on "Purchased" in the right-hand navigation bar, select Apps at the top, and then click the download button next to any app you'd like to download.

Comment: Thanks! There's also a Download All button at the bottom, which is exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this works in all countries. Only music/movies/tv shows are restricted to specific countries.

Comment: Doesn't work in the latest iTunes - "Not in my library" is empty and "All" is full of apps that don't exist on my system. Will post a solution if I find one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also "**Transfer Purchases**" from a device to your computer.  This is what I had to do when moving from an iPad 2 to iPad 4, to get the apps to transfer across properly.

[image]